# OpenCV - Making a video from existing images

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, video

I have an array of numpy array images named images. Let's say for the discussion's sake that -

```
images = [cv2.imread("data/frame" + str(i) + ".jpg") for i in range(15)]
```

Where data is a directory with frames from a video. 
I then try to save them as a video, using the following code:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
shape = images[0].shape[:2]
vid = cv2.VideoWriter("my_vid.avi", fourcc, 1, shape)
for fg_frame in images:
    vid.write(np.uint8(fg_frame))
vid.release()
```

But the video that is saved is only 5-6 KB in size and plays nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps there is no needed codec in your system (or OpenCV does not find it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the constructor of `cv2.VideoWriter` takes video size in the 4th argument which is expected to be a tuple of the form `(width, height)`.

The `shape` member of `numpy` array stores dimensions as `(height, width)`.

Due to dimension mismatch between `VideoWriter` and the actual image, no frames are written to the disk.

You have to swap the elements of `shape` when passing as an argument to `VideoWriter`. The correct code may look like this:

```
shape = images[0].shape[:2]
video_size = (shape[1], shape[0])
vid = cv2.VideoWriter("my_vid.avi", fourcc, 1, video_size)
```

Verified and tested on Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 3 and OpenCV 3.4.